# division animate issue on jquery window scroll

Tags: jquery

i want to animate division on window scroll, its only animate when scrollTop is greater than 200, and when i want to scroll back on  scrollTop greater > 500 it does nothing.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var posFromTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    if(posFromTop > 200){
        // if more than 200px from the top do something
        $('#banner').animate({'left': +300});}            

    if(posFromTop > 500){
        // if more than 200px from the top do something
        $('#banner').animate('left': -300});}
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are more then 500 pixels from the top, both animations are started at the same time and cancel each other out. Try changing the

```
if(posFromTop > 200){
```

to

```
if(posFromTop > 200 && posfromTop <= 500){
```

Comment: still not working
colors are changing but animation is not working when position is greater than 600

$(window).scroll(function(){

        var posFromTop = $(window).scrollTop();

   $("#scrollValue").html(posFromTop)

        if(posFromTop > 200 && posFromTop <= 500){
    
      $('#scrollValue').css({'background-color': 'blue'});
   $('#scrollValue').animate({'marginLeft': 200});}
   
    if(posFromTop > 600 && posFromTop <= 1000){
  $('#scrollValue').css({'background-color': 'brown'});
      $('#scrollValue').animate({'marginLeft': 0});}

    });

Comment: Could you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), your code is not readable as a comment.

Comment: There was an error with jQuery version 1.10.1 so I tried it with version 1.9.1 (and added a few lines of text, so I could scroll over 600 pixels) and it worked fine then: [new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GxFJj/6/)

Comment: thanks, but it takes pause and then animate, what's the problem?